# Count of Reports With Dashboards

Tags: reporting, dashboard, custom-report-type

**How can the Count of 'Reports With Dashboard' be greater than the 'Total Count of Reports'? Am I misinterpreting the data?**

1. When I ran the following query in Workbench I got the count as **132435**

   **`SELECT count() FROM Report`**

   The Report 'All Reports' , 'Created Date All Time' gave the same count
   i.e. 132435
2. Next I wanted to find **how many of these 132435 reports are on a Dashboard.**

   For that, I created a report based on the ReportType 'Report With or Without Dashboards'

   [image]

   Report created is as follows -

   **Filters:**
   Show Me = All reports
   Created Date = All Time

   **Included columns** ‘Report Name’, ‘Last Run’, 'Dashboard Title'

   Sorted the report by Title ascending to separate the reports that are not attached to dashboards.
3. After running the Report and exporting to excel -

   **Total count of rows in the excel file**  **193,840**

   Why is the count from 'Reports with Dashboards' is so much higher than the count of  Reports obtained from the report 'All Reports Created All Time'?
4. **The Count of Reports With Dashboards = 137338**

   I am wondering how is the Count of Reports with Dashboards greater than the total number of Dashboards?

Comment: If a report is used in multiple dashboards, won't it be counted multiple times?

Comment: Yes, if a report is used in multiple dashboards it will be counted multiple times. I thought i  would get a distinct count of reports.  Is there a way to get a distinct count of report with dashboards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, reports can be used across many different dashboards. What you're looking for can be easily achieved with a SOQL

`SELECT count() FROM Report WHERE Id IN (SELECT CustomReportId FROM DashboardComponent`

The above will give you the actual number you're interested in: # of unique reports on dashboards

---

In your existing report you can also achieve this by showing a unique count

[image]

1. Add the `Report Id` column
2. Click on the down arrow in the column
3. Select `Show Unique Count`

[image]